In a linearly ordered semigroup, are intervals sent into convex sets by multiplications?
I'm following Fuchs's notation from the book "Partially Ordered Algebraic Systems".
A linearly ordered semigroup is a tuple $(S, \leq, +, 0)$  satisfying

$(S, +, 0)$ is a semigroup with identity $0$ (we can assume it is commutative if needed).
$(S, \leq)$ is a linear order with minimum $0$.
The order is strictly translation invariant, i.e. $a<b$ implies $a+c<b+c$ and $c+a<c+b$ for all $a,b,c\in S$.

My question is:
Consider $a\in S$ and the interval $[0,a]=\{b\in S\mid b\leq a\}$. Is $c+[0,a]=\{c+b\mid b\leq a\}$ still convex?
(where we say that $A\subseteq S$ is convex if for every $a,b, c\in S$, if $a\leq b\leq c$ and $a,c\in A$ then also $b\in A$).
Also, if someone has a reference for a book where to study similar properties of linearly ordered semigroups, this would be very appreciated (a similar reference request was asked in this old question that never received an answer).

No.
Consider $S = ([0,1] \cap \mathbb Q) \cup \{x \in \mathbb R: x \geq 1\}$, with usual order and sum.
Then, for every rational $c \neq 0$ in $S$, we have that $c + ([0,1] \cap \mathbb Q)$ is still a set of rational numbers, but there are irrationals in between.
For example, take $c=1$, and
$$c + ([0,1] \cap \mathbb Q) = [1,2] \cap \mathbb Q,$$
which doesn't include $\sqrt{2}$, although $1 < \sqrt{2} < 2$.
